# Python: Loop over each column/row accordingly & subtract value between two csv files

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, csv, opencv3.0, subtraction

I want to subtract each value (test.csv) with every row value in each column (input.csv). For example, 0.0010 (test.csv) - 0.0023 (input.csv) and 0.0010 (test.csv) - 0.0030 (input.csv) followed by the next number in test.csv with the next column in input.csv, 0.8236 (test.csv) - 8.6932 (input.csv) and 0.8236 (test.csv) - 16.881 (input.csv). However,i only manage to subtract the first value of test.csv with the first column in input.csv.

Is there anyone can give me any idea to solve this issue?

input.csv -

- 0.0023  8.6932  0.9976
- 0.0030  16.881  0.9975

test.csv  -

- 0.0010
- 0.8236
- 0.1165
- 0.1789
- 0.1760
- 1.4450

But, what i get is

- .... , 0.0010 , 0.0023
- .... , 0.0010 , 0.0030
- .... , 0.8236
- .... , 0.1165
- .... , 0.1789
- .... , 0.1760
- .... , 1.4450

My expected output is something like this

- .... , 0.0010 , 0.0023
- .... , 0.0010 , 0.0030
- .... , 0.8236 , 8.6932
- .... , 0.8236 , 16.881
- .... , 0.1165 , 0.9976
- .... , 0.1165 , 0.9975

Thanks

```
f1=open('input.csv')
csv_f1 = csv.reader(f1)
f2=open('test.csv')
csv_f2 = csv.reader(f2)

y=0
for row in csv_f2:
   test_data = np.array([float(row[y])])
   for row in csv_f1:
       all_data = np.array([float(row[x])])
       result = (test_data  -   all_data)
       print ("Expected",test_data,all_data)
```

Comment: I think your outer loop is advancing one row at a time, and you want it to advance the y and start over at every "last" iteration

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

I'm adding this just so this can be marked as answered/solved.
there was a logical bug, my comment:

> to advance the y and start over at every "last" iteration

solved the issue.